Array is length 0 zero even though the debug console shows it has items
I have the oddest problem. All other answers on here seem to be about awaiting stuff, which doesn't apply here; the source JSON is in the HTML.
An array containing items somehow has zero length and the forEach won't iterate it. See my console output below.
// Container class

public inspectionTypes: SelectionOption[] = [];

// further down

public initializeInspectionTypes(types: any[]) {

    if (types) {

        types.forEach(t => {

            this.inspectionTypes.push(t);
        });
    }
}

// Some other class

console.debug('Type:', typeof container.inspectionTypes);
console.debug('Is Array:', Array.isArray(container.inspectionTypes));
console.debug('Length:', container.inspectionTypes.length);
console.debug(container.inspectionTypes);

container.inspectionTypes.forEach(option => {

    console.debug(option);

    // this.inspectionTypes().push(option);

});

As you can see, the length is 0 but sending the inspectionTypes to the console does show it is populated.

And here it is with inspectionTypes logged first, in case you're thinking it gets emptied somehow.


"Freeze" it by logging a structuredClone or JSON.stringify result. Failing that, please give a [mre] showing how you're actually creating and using the object.

The values of the array you see are the current values of the array in memory. So for example if you were to take this simplified example...
let myArray = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

console.log(myArray.length); // 3
console.log(myArray);

myArray.pop()
myArray.pop()

console.log(myArray.length); // 1
console.log(myArray);

myArray.push('new')

Note the array reference never changes. So in this case we get the correct values at the time of the console.log but when you expand the array in the browser console, that is showing the current reference to the array.
So if you run the case above in the browser and expand the values it would look like this...

Notice the first log shows ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] but the values of the array shows ['foo', 'new'] this is the live reference to the array.
Alternatively, if you were to change the reference of the array by reassigning the myArray variable, like below.
let myArray = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

console.log(myArray.length); // 3
console.log(myArray);

myArray = ['foo']

console.log(myArray.length); // 1
console.log(myArray);

myArray.push('new')


The first console.log of the array still shows the values, this is because this holds a reference to the original array ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], but the second console log still has the issue because that array references the new array (i.e. ['foo']) which was never reassigned, we only used pop and push to alter that array.

In the end this should not matter in terms of your code.

This is also why it's better to debugger the code than rely on the simple console.log. If you were to debug the code examples above at each console.log, you would be able to see the correct live value of the array reference.
